# Reinstalling packages on new version of R

Tags: package-management, 20.04, r

I have recently updated the new version of R (4.02) each time I want to use a library a message like this appears "Error: package ‘rmarkdown’ was installed before R 4.0.0: please re-install it"
for each of my libraries, so I install each one of them with this command

```
sudo su - -c "R -e \"install.packages('shiny', repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/', dependencies = TRUE)\""
```

Even with the reinstallation of my libraries I am not able to install "shiny", when I try to install shiny I have this issue

```
Error: package ‘rmarkdown’ was installed before R 4.0.0: please re-install it
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘flexdashboard’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/flexdashboard’
ERROR: dependency ‘debugme’ is not available for package ‘webdriver’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/webdriver’
ERROR: dependencies ‘debugme’, ‘pingr’, ‘webdriver’ are not available for package ‘shinytest’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/shinytest’
```

I am not sure if the best way to have a clean env is uninstalling R.

Thanks for your help